# Deserialize JSON with variable property names in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize the following JSON for an in-house application.

```
{
  "resources": [
    "output.ogg",
    "output.m4a",
    "output.mp3",
    "output.ac3"
  ],
  "spritemap": {
    "click": {
      "start": 0,
      "end": 0.23034013605442177,
      "loop": false
    },
    "CoinCMixed": {
      "start": 2,
      "end": 2.222448979591837,
      "loop": false
    },
    "CoinDropMixed": {
      "start": 4,
      "end": 4.312222222222222,
      "loop": false
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the Name (e.g. "click") and the `start` and `end` values.

The problem is, the name isn't always the same thing. It's unique. So, I'm guessing what I need to do is loop through `spritemap`?  But I don't know how to do that.

So, for example:

- Name: CoinDropMixed
- start: 4
- end: 4.3122222

Which would allow me to do

```
msgbox("Your song name is " + Name + "The length is " + start + "The end is" + end)
```

Comment: Edit, I added the entire JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the varying names by using a `Dictionary`.  Define your classes like this:

```
Class DataObject
    Public Property resources As List(Of String)
    Public Property spritemap As Dictionary(Of String, Sound)
End Class

Class Sound
    Public Property start As Double
    Public Property [end] As Double
    Public Property [loop] As Boolean
End Class
```

Then you can deserilalize the JSON like this:

```
Dim data As DataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataObject)(json)
```

You can then loop over the dictionary like this to get the data you want:

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Sound) In data.spritemap
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + kvp.Key)
    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + kvp.Value.start.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("End: " + kvp.Value.end.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TxSy0i

Answer (score 0):

if the name is varibale it is hard to deserialize and inspect the object using reflection.

also your json in not well formatted, you need a root container {}

```
{
  "click": {
    "start": 0,
    "end": 0.23034013605442177,
    "loop": false
  },
    "CoinCMixed": {
    "start": 2,
    "end": 2.222448979591837,
    "loop": false
  },
  "CoinDropMixed": {
    "start": 4,
    "end": 4.312222222222222,
    "loop": false
  }
}
```

in this case it could be a good solution to manually parse the json string.
this is my solution (not tested)

```
dim s as String = "JSON TEXT"
dim level as Integer  = 0
dim stringStatus as Integer  = 0
dim tmp as String =""
dim result  as List(Of String) = new List(Of String)
for i as Integer =0 to (s.Length -1)
    String c = s.Chars(i)
    if c="{" then level = level +1
    if c="}" then level = level -1
    if (c="""" or c="'") and stringStatus = 0  then stringStatus  = 1
    elseif (c="""" or c="'") and stringStatus  = 1 then 
        stringStatus = 0
        if level = 1 then result.add(tmp)
        tmp=""
    elseif stringStatus  = 1 then
        tmp = tmp + c
    end if
next
```

Now result contains a list of your names....
working on this base you can retreive other data like start, end,loop, for each node...